# Bootstrap Popover on Floated Element

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot seem to figure out how to put a popover on a element that is floating (in this case to the left)

Whenever I apply a popover it goes to the top-left of the parent container but when I remove the float css, the popover works fine.

Demo: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/oNc6AJTWNd#)

**HTML**

```
<a class="popper" href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-html="true" data-content="test textbox">
    <img class="avatar" src="http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&amp;size=l&amp;tid=51287906" height="60" width="60">
</a>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function ()  
  {
    $('.popper').popover({
    trigger: 'click',
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.avatar {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
  border:2px solid black;
  border-radius: 500px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
  -moz-border-radius: 500px;
  float:left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so float popper

```
.popper{float:left;}
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/X0x7xui3AT)